# Using wp_localize_script to store the template url into a variable to use in JS

Tags: php, jquery, javascript, wp-localize-script

I was trying to store the template url (`bloginfo(template_url);`) into a variable so I could use it in my JavaScript. However, I realized this wasn't possible and someone alerted me to `wp_localize_script` and said that it could do what I wanted. I looked through the codex but I'm still unsure as to how to implement this.

Here's what I have so far:

Function

```
function starter_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'templateUrl', array(
        'templateUrl' => template_url()
        ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starter_scripts' );
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Fade in Contact background
    $('body.page-template-page-contact #content').css('background', 'url(templateUrl + bg-contact.jpg) 50% 0% no-repeat fixed').fadeIn(2000);

});
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Update:

```
function starter_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'starter-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'includes', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/min/includes.min.js', '', '', true );

    wp_localize_script( 'includes', 'site', array(
        'url'         => site_url('/'),
        'theme_path'  => get_template_directory_uri(),
        'templateUrl' => template_url()
        ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'starter_scripts' );
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Fade in Contact background
    $('body.page-template-page-contact #content').css('background', 'url(site.templateUrl/img/bg-contact.jpg) 50% 0% no-repeat fixed').fadeIn(2000);

});
```

Comment: I'd say that this `'url(site.templateUrl + bg-contact.jpg)` is kind of wrong. `'url(' + site.templateUrl + 'bg-contact.jpg)` should work a bit better though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not enqueueing your custom JavaScript file. And calling the var (`templateUrl`) in JS file without the handle. Follow the following:

I'm enqueueing my custom JavaScripts file (`script.js`) under the dependency of jQuery, so it will enqueue jQuery library from core. And I'm using the same handle `my-custom-js` for both my script and localize_script to pass the variables to the JavaScripts page.

**`functions.php`**

```
<?php
function project_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( "my-custom-js", get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/script.js", array("jquery"), "20141230", TRUE );
    wp_localize_script("my-custom-js",
                            "site",
                            array(
                                    "theme_path"    => get_template_directory_uri()
                                )
                        );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'project_scripts' );
```

**`script.js`**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    console.log(site.theme_path);

});
```

**Note** the `site` handle in both localize_script and my custom JS file - it's the key with which I'm fetching the data.

Comment: When you say "custom JavaScript file," are you referring to the file where I plan on using the variable created with `wp_localize_script`?

Comment: Yes. Please refresh the page, and see the complete answer.

Comment: I tried to follow your example but I ended up with `undefined function template_url()`. I updated my post with the changes. Can you help me out?

Comment: There is no such function like `template_url()`, use `get_bloginfo('template_url')` - updated my answer.

Comment: And more useful will be, if you can use the `theme_path` where I used `get_template_directory_uri()`

Comment: Thank you. I used `theme_path` and it worked. Can I delete the third line `templateUrl => get_bloginfo('template_url')` then? Also, do I need the first line `url => site_url`?

Comment: Yes, why not? :) and No, you don't, it's what I's using. :) You can remove both of the above mentioned. So I'm editing my answer as your need. :)

Comment: Ok, perfect, thank you. I was confused because I thought they were needed in order to function correctly. But I guess `url => site_url` can be useful so I think I will keep that. :)